# REACT NATIVE - how to make react native marquee keep running when I use setInterval in ComponentdidMount to auto reload data from API

Tags: mobile, react-native, react-native-ios

I just start learning react-native and currently build an customer queue application for a hospital using react native. My queue main page has 2 main component: queue table and news running text (using react-native-marquee). I need to get data from server every 5000ms to make this app realtime, so use

```
  componentDidMount(){
        this._interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
    }, 5000);
}
```

`makeRemoteRequest()` is my method to fetch data from my API.
but the problem is my news running text stop working. Is there any way  to get data from server every 5sec but keep the marquee running??

fell free to ask if you  need more information. . .

Answer (score 0):

in your `makeRemoteRequest()` function **after receiving** your new data just use **`this.setState`** method to show it in your desired component like this:

```
this.setState({
    your_marquee_text: dataFetchedFromServer
});
```

And in your component use it like this:

```
<Text>{this.state.your_marquee_text}</Text>
```

Comment: I solve this problem with separating marquee remote request and queue data remote request because I only need to call marquee data remote request 1 times but need to call queue data remote request every 1 sec using set_interval. So I move marquee component and its remote request function to a new page so it only calls one time. 

Thanks, Hossein